# Is there a 'reader view' in Opera browser?

Tags: opera

The reader view in Firefox browser is very useful.

Is there something similar in Opera browser? May be, a setting within Opera itself or an add-on?

But if it is an add-on, it needs to convert the page locally i.e. without a third party service.

Also, I am running Opera on a Fedora24 Workstation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and install Opera :)
2. Download and install the Opera extension called "Download Chrome Extension" at https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/app_id/kipjbhgniklcnglfaldilecjomjaddfi in Opera
3. Download and install the *Chrome* extension called "Chrome Reader View" at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-reader-view/eeblcnjajoammeoofffcejdmklpmfcci *in Opera*
4. Enjoy Reader View in Opera. :)

The problem I have with this setup is that my Opera Vimium keyboard shortcuts don't work in Reader View, which makes this setup inferior to my Reader View experience in Firefox (with usable keyboard shortcuts).  But it is better than nothing.  I am still looking for how to overcome that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Opera can install Chrome extensions. There are multiple reader view extension in Chrome.

Check here for [more must-have google chrome extensions](https://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2019/04/must-have-google-chrome-extensions.html)

#### Chrome Extensions for Reading

[Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh)

- Also enable Mac's dark mode at Preferences -> General

Summary

- Use [Reader View](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reader-view/ecabifbgmdmgdllomnfinbmaellmclnh) when the page(website) is slow: load lots of ads, flash, uses a lot of memory and you will take time(2+ mins) to read it.
- Use [Just Read](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/just-read/dgmanlpmmkibanfdgjocnabmcaclkmod) in other case.
- Use [Clearly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clearly/odfonlkabodgbolnmmkdijkaeggofoop) to check the outline.